# render a CharField as checkbox in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-widget

Is it possible to render a Django model CharField as a checkbox? I need this checkbox on admin edit page as well as the `list_editable` list page. E.g. when checked, set this CharField value to `'t'`, else set it to `'n'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a form changing the widgets no matter the type you are using.
Here is the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/)

Then if you need to change other things depending on the input people gives I guess you should do some jQuery creating a $('#mycheckboxid').click function